# Comparar arrays e destacar as alterações

Tags: php, array

estou com um probleminha que não estou conseguindo resolver.
Eu tenho um array com um histórico de ocorrências que possui 5 posições, e preciso fazer a exibição desses históricos destacando os itens diferentes de cada array.
No momento eu consigo pegar a diferença entre dois deles, porém não estou conseguindo perceber o melhor modo de receber todas as diferenças.

```
$diff = array_diff($historico[3], $historico[4]);
```

Nesse caso ficam faltando os historicos da posição 2,1 e 0.

A estrutura do array que eu tenho é essa:

```
[
[0] => Array
    (         
        [0] => 07/06/2018 15:49:00
        [1] => Questionamento :  teste questionamento  
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 07/06/2018 15:50:00
        [1] => Questionamento :  teste questionamento 2
    )
 [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 07/06/2018 15:51:00
        [1] => Questionamento :  teste questionamento 3
    )
 [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 07/06/2018 15:52:00
        [1] => Questionamento :  teste questionamento 4
    )
  [4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 07/06/2018 15:53:00
        [1] => Questionamento :  teste questionamento 5
    )
```

]

Comment: é array dentro de array?

Comment: Tipo dentro do array historico tem 5 arrays?

Comment: Sim é um array de histórico com um array para cada atualização.

Comment: Imagino que terá que fazer um loop recursivo, pegando cada um e comparando com o restante

Comment: Só você colocar os outros arrays ai dentro ué, $diff = array_diff($historico[0],$historico[1],$historico[2],$historico[3],$historico[4]);

Comment: @Anderson Henrique dessa maneira não funcionou.

Comment: @Marcelo tenho que comparar o último com o penúltimo, o penúltimo com o antepenúltimo, até chegar no primeiro.

Comment: Você pode ordenar o array antes de acomparar, https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei o motivo, mas se quer pegar de trás para frente faça assim

```
#array para pegar as diferenças
$diferencas = array();
#for pegando o tamanho do array e diminuindo, o motivo do menos 1 é que o array inicia de 0 então mesmo tendo 4 registros seriam de 0 a 3 no caso 3, teria que diminuir 1
for($i = sizeof($historico) - 1; $i > 0; $i--):
    #adiciona a comparacao de array da posicao atual com uma anterior
    array_push($diferencas,array_diff($historico[$i],$historico[$i - 1]));
endfor;
#printa as diferencas
print_r($diferencas);
```

Você também pode ter outra forma sem precisar dos menos

```
 #array para pegar as diferenças
$diferencas = array();
#Reverte as posicoes dos arrays de tras pra frente, ultimas chaves viram primeiras
krsort($historico);
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($historico) - 1; $i++):
array_push($diferencas,array_diff($historico[$i],$historico[$i + 1]));  
endfor;
print_r($diferencas);
```

Comment: Obrigado, dessa maneira funcionou corretamente.

Comment: Denada, se puder por favor marcar como resposta eu agradeço. @ValdirSilva